# How to set access restrictions using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I have some function apps and I found how to allow access to Azure cloud by following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions. But I use ARM template to deploy the function apps and every time I do a deployment, the restrictions are gone. So, I would like to include the access restriction in my ARM template so add the restrictions every time they get deployed. I couldn't find a relevant resource anywhere to do this. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Maybe set up the function app how you want it manually via the portal, then select the resource in the resourcegroup view and "export template"? this will generate an arm template for the selected resources and will perhaps include the ip restrictions you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested by @classicSchmosby98 that would be one of the solutions to restrict the azure function app using ARM template.*

- *Create your own azure function manually from portal and add all the restrictions what you need.*
- *Now export the template from the resource group for your resource with this you can even include the IP restrictions.*
- *Also, you can go through the [Assign roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-template) using Azure Manager templates.*
- *For more information you can refer explore [ARM templates.](https://www.varonis.com/blog/arm-template)*